# @Inject gives a NullPointer Exception in java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a webservice that gives some results taken through hibernate from the database.

```
@Path("/book")
public class BookService {

    @Inject
    private dbController db;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getBookTitle() {
        return "H2G2";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUsers(){

        List<UserEntity> users = db.getUsers();


        return Response.ok(users,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

the db variable whenever I call http://localhost/book/users is always null.

The dbController is:

```
public class dbController {

    @Inject
    private HibernateUtil util;

    public List<UserEntity> getUsers(){

        List<UserEntity> result = null;
        try{
            result = (List<UserEntity>) this.util.createQuery("select e from UserEntity e");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and the HibernateUtil is:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
    private EntityManager entityManager = null;


    private void createEntityManager(){
        if (this.entityManager==null){
            this.entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); // here is your persistence unit name
        }


    }

    private void closeConnection(){
        this.entityManager.close();
        this.entityManager = null;
    }

    public List createQuery(String query) throws Exception{
        this.createEntityManager();
        List result;

        try{
            result = this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }


}
```

I'm using intellij and I added a break point at the db.getUsers() and set the variable db by adding new dbController(). However, the Intellij gives me the error "Class not loaded : controller.dbController".

The hibernate works for sure...so the problem is not there. It's the first time I'm trying to use Dependency Injection, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any annotation on your `HibernateUtil` class?

Comment: No...I don't have any

Comment: Is this the whole code you have (excluding imports)?

Comment: I didn't consider important the imports...they are just for instance import javax.ws.rs.GET; etc...the only thing is that dbController is in controller package, HibernateUtil is in model package and BookService in webservice package

Comment: Yes exactly that i meant with excluding imports, they really are not so relevevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inject POJO it has to be a Bean. So making it a bean requires the annotations, for example:

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class dbController {..} // Should be DbController, start with CAPS
```

and

```
@Stateful // or maybe @Stateless ?
@LocalBean
public class HibernateUtil {..}
```

Then when you have a Bean it is not allowed to use `static final` so change like this is needed:

```
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
```

**But actually** the easiest way to get `EntityManager` is just to inject it also. Like:

```
@PersistenceContext// maybe also with unit name (unitName = "whatever_the_unit_name_is")
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: I've tried it but I still get the same error. I have also included in the pom.xml https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0, but without any success. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SymeonMattes What app server do you use?The api is just api not an implementation.

Comment: jboss 7.5.0...I'm using also Intellij ultimate edition and SDK 1.8.0_191

Comment: @SymeonMattes when I used JAX-RS there was also a need to add `@Singleton` (maybe some other bean type is more appropriate but it usually is a singleton) to my service class so try to add it to your `BookService` to have injection done.

Comment: I added under @Path("/book") the annotation @Singleton but again without success. I keep receiving the same Exception

Comment: @SymeonMattes Does it run if you deploy it -say- as a WAR? Possible logs if not. Try also to first comment out injection of `HibernateUtil` in your `dbController`. And also chansge it ot `DbController` it is a class naming convention. Maybe you just need some more setting in idea to debug EE it needs more stuff configured than SE

Comment: Actually in the target it doesn't have a war file but a jar. When I created the project I used maven quickstart prototype...not the webapp.

Comment: The answer you gave me worked...finally. I had to add JavaEE support. In intellij Right click on the project->Add Framework Support->CDI:Context and Dependency Injection and Use Library Maven:org.glassfish.jersey.bundles:jaxrs-ri:2.25