# Creating a simple app with Dependency Injection in Java with Intellij

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm trying to create a simple project with RX-JS project that uses some classes through DI. However I get a NullPointer Exception which it means the DI is not working properly.

Then in src/main/java/webservice/Services.java

```
@Path("/")
public class Services {

        @Inject
        private ConfigFileEntity cfe;
        @GET
        @Path("/books")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getBooks(){
            cfe.readFile();
            return Response.ok().build();

        }
}
```

and in src/main/java/webservice/ConfigFileEntity.java

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class ConfigFileEntity {

    private Properties readFile() throws Exception {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try{

            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("A path");
            prop.load(is);

            return prop;

        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have also a src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

I had made a similar question in [inject gives a nullpointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437998/inject-gives-a-nullpointer-exception-in-java-ee/54442104) however I changed machine (linux to windows) and Application Server (JBoss to Glassfish). So I'm not sure what I've made wrong.

The structure of my project is:
[image: Structure of Project]

And the pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>webservice</groupId>
  <artifactId>webservice</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>webservice</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
      <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thanks

Comment: I do not see a getFile() method in your injected class, only a readFile() method. Not sure if this is a mistake or just something done for  brevity.

Comment: Sorry...I'm fixing it...it's a typo

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your service class with some annotation to make it discoverable to the container. If it is service class, I would recommend to use @Service annotation and try again.

Comment: Ι think @ Service is in Spring. I'm using JavaEE. I've tried to put @ RequestScoped but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes..that is specific to Spring. In your case, you are using CDI(Context and Dependecny Injection) for dependency injection. It seems your beans.xml is not in class path. Can you paste your entire code for clarity like pom.xml and hierarchy structure of your codebase

Comment: Ok...I updated the answer. The beans.xml has been put in resources/META-INF by Intellij when I right click on the root project->Add Framework Support->Click CDI:Contexts and Dependency

Comment: Hi @SymeonMattes,  

In JavaEE to create a rest endpoint, you first need to configure the entry point   
  for all rest resources. To do this, you will need to create a new class in your 
 project, as seen below:  
    import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;   
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;   

    @ApplicationPath("rest")  
    public class RestConfiguration extends Application {  
   
    }

Comment: Hi...I have already done this...it's in the App.java file in the image above. I didn't write anything for that because my issu is not in the REST api which works but in Dependency Injection

Comment: I think beans.xml has been put at wrong place. It should be placed within a folder Webapp/WEB-INF folder. Let me try with intellj Id and get back to you.

Comment: I have tried also in that place but it didn't work. Intellij put in the place I have currently.

Comment: For some reason with Java EE8 it works...but not with EE7